# SQL: Selecting a minimum value per unique group and changing values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

**ID  Date  Category**

```
x   1995      A
x   1996      B
z   1995      B
z   1996      A
y   1995      B
y   1996      B
```

What I want to do is to set the Category to whatever the value is for the minimum date per ID. So that the final result would look like:

**ID  Date  Category**

```
x   1995      A
x   1996      A
z   1995      B
z   1996      B
y   1995      B
y   1996      B
```

Does anyone know how to do this in SQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @t table (id char(1), date int, category char(1))
insert into @t
select 'x',   1995,      'A' union all
select 'x',   1996 ,     'B'  union all
select 'z',   1995  ,    'B' union all
select 'z',   1996   ,   'A' union all
select 'y',   1995    ,  'B' union all
select 'y',   1996     , 'B'

select t1.Id,t1.Date,t2.category from @t as t1 left join
( 
select t1.Id,t1.Date,t1.category from @t as t1 inner join
    (
    select ID, min(Date) as Date from @t group by ID
    ) as t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id and t1.Date=t2.Date
) as t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id
```

Comment: group by will return 3 rows and inner join will ultimately return 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it although there might be a smarter way:

```
select table1.id, table1.date, t3.category 
from table1
join (
  select t1.id, t1.category
  from table1 t1
  join (
    select id, min(date) as min_date 
    from table1 
    group by id
  ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.min_date
) t3 on table1.id = t3.id
```

In the query your source table is named `table1`. The logic is that the inner derived table limits the outer to the min(date)

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f5c2/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select 
  id,
  date,
  (
    select category 
    from mytable x
    where x.id = m.id
    and not exists
    (
      select * 
      from mytable older
      where older.id = x.id 
      and older.date < x.date
    )
  ) as oldest_category
from mytable m;
```